# Storing plain text passwords

Tags: php, air, passwords

I'm working on an AIR application with a web back end. I need to store passwords for other websites (like how some websites do).

What is the best way to store those passwords and transfer them between the PHP back end and the AIR application?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Encrypt them on the back end and only transfer them over SSL protected channels.
- Use [OpenID](http://openid.net)

Answer (score 0):

If possible store the passwords on the users machine and never transfer them to your back end web service. If you choose not to do so then when your server is compromised all those passwords will more than likely be stolen.

Services such as [lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) wish their users to be able to access their passwords no matter what machine they are on so they encrypt and decrypt everything on the user's side and only ever transfer the encrypted passwords to their server. The key which is needed to decrypt the passwords is only ever in the end user's head (or on their machine if they choose to save it) and is never transfered to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Only store them on the client PC, hopefully encrypted, then login using javascript xmlhttprequest.

Answer (score -3):

Store them as MD5 hashes in the database.

Comment: Not going to do it, as if they're storing usernames and passwords for OTHER sites, then one presumes they are going to log into those sites and thus need the passwords to be retrievable.

Comment: ? You lost me. You can easily retrieve the passwords by checking the db hash against the posted value (passed into md5())

Why I got a -3 rating by just stating normal web practice eludes me.

Comment: Can someone please explain why I got -3?!

Comment: A bit late to the party, but the idea is that the stored passwords are for ANOTHER service, so he cannot do the normal procedure of hashing the password and than comparing the hashed version of new input to the hashed stored in the database.